# What event listener should I use for on-screen keyboard if not keyEvents?

Tags: java, swing, events, jtextfield, on-screen-keyboard

I have a code that goes like this in my java swing program:

```
  JTextField textfield = (JTextField) txtNameID.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
  textfield.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
            
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    comboFilter(textfield.getText());
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

It's function is to show names from database that's like what is being typed on the textfield. It should show up once the user started typing.

Like this:
[image]

And this works well when using hard keyboard. But my problem is I have to use an on screen keyboard/virtual keyboard for this program and KeyListener doesn't work with it. Now I don't know what type of event listener I should use. I tried MouseListener but it doesn't work also. I hope there is a way. I really need this for my project. Please kindly help me out.

This is my code for the on-screen keyboard(on the same class, it has a longer code in a different class):

```
   textfield.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                  DialogVirtualKeyboardReal dlg = new DialogVirtualKeyboardReal(this, false, textfield);
                     dlg.setLocaleL(locale);
        }
    });
    
     textfield.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            DialogVirtualKeyboardReal dlg = new DialogVirtualKeyboardReal(r, false, textfield);
                     dlg.setLocaleL(locale);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
          
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
           
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            
        }
    });
```

Here's a picture of the DialogVirtualKeyboardReal:
[image]

The keys are made of JButtons.

---

EDITED:
I tried DocumentListener following the instructions of @Abra.

The keyboard pops up, but it disappears after 1 letter typed in the textfield and the names below the textfield pops up.

It's good that the comboFilter appears even when I type from virtual keyboard. But I want it to execute simultaneously, while typing on the virtual keyboard, the comboFilter should appear.

Another thing is that it had an error with my database.

This is the code I created:

```
     JTextField textfield = (JTextField) txtNameID.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
   textfield.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
         filter();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            filter();
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            filter();
        }
        public void filter(){
             SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                comboFilter(textfield.getText());
            }});
        }           });
```

And the error is:

```
  errorcom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
```

The comboFilter() code is:

```
public void comboFilter(String enteredText) {
List<String> filterArray= new ArrayList<String>();

        String lname="";
        String fname= "";
        String mi= "";
        String id= "";

 try{
String str="SELECT * FROM patient_record WHERE firstname  LIKE '"+enteredText+"%' OR lastname  LIKE '"+enteredText+"%' OR patient_id  LIKE '"+enteredText+"%'";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/patient";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");

 Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(str);
 while(rs.next()){
  lname=rs.getString("lastname");
  fname= rs.getString("firstname");
  mi= rs.getString("middlename");
  id= rs.getString("patient_id");
  String str1 = lname+", "+fname+" "+mi+". \t"+id;
  filterArray.add(str1);
 }}
catch(Exception ex){
 System.out.println("error"+ex);   
}

if (filterArray.size() > 0) {
    jComboBox1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(filterArray.toArray()));
    jComboBox1.setSelectedItem(enteredText);
    jComboBox1.showPopup();
}
else {
    jComboBox1.hidePopup();
} 
}
```

I know the way I explained it is difficult to understand. Please bear with me. You guys may ask for further questions to better understand my question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is a JDialog which is a Swing Window. And yes, it is DialogVirtualKeyboardReal.

Comment: I've added a picture of the virtual keyboard @Abra, yes the keys are JButtons

Comment: So when the user "presses" a key on the virtual keyboard, you want your application to react in the same way as if he entered a letter into the `JTextField`, correct? In fact, this `JTextField` is actually the editor component of an editable `JComboBox`, correct?

Comment: Yes yes. Exactly. Sorry I couldn't explain it well.

Comment: Looking at the code for the virtual keyboard it has a constructor `DialogVirtualKeyboardReal(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal, JTextComponent textComponent)` which accepts a `JTextComponent` I.e. a `JTextField` so I assume it will automatically add keys pressed to the textfield. In your code you initialise the  `DialogVirtualKeyboardReal` inside the `ActionListener` of the textfield. This is incorrect simply move the code outside of the `ActionListener ` and I'm sure all will work ?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp it doesn't work :( And I only need the virtual keyboard when I click the textfield/combobox.

Comment: Post some code that reproduces your problem so you can get better help faster.

Comment: I've edited my post, could you check it again @DavidKroukamp

Answer (score 1):

So I've made a small example to help you, but before that:

1. Your SQL error "Too many connections", you probbaly want to do `con.close()` in ALL places you open a connection to the database like this:

   ```
    Connection con = null
    try {
        // create the connection and do your database work here
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // log your exception here
    } finally {
        if (con != null) {
            // finally lets close the connection (event in the event of a exception)
            con.close();
        }
    }
   ```
2. The `DialogVirtualKeyboardReal` code (no offence to the author is not the best as it doesn't cater well for the scenario of the keyboard not being *modal*), so you cant have the dialog show while typing unless you make it *modal* i.e. pass `true` into the `DialogVirtualKeyboardReal` constructor (which is what my example does), or make changes to the actual `DialogVirtualKeyboardReal`, but thats a whole new topic.
3. Because of my above statement it doesnt make sense to show the `JComboBox` popup as you type as it potentially will cover the keyboard.

With all that said I hope this helps get you started (my `comboFilter` method simply mocks up a response as if it was a result from the database):

[image]

**TestApp.java**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class TestApp {

    private JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
    private final ArrayList<String> listOfNames = new ArrayList<>();

    public TestApp() {
        listOfNames.add("David Kroukamp");
        listOfNames.add("Abra");
        listOfNames.add("Camickr");
        listOfNames.add("Hovercraft Full Of Eels");
        listOfNames.add("Andrew Thompson");
        listOfNames.add("MadProgrammer");
        listOfNames.add("TrashGod");
        listOfNames.add("Gilbert Le Blanc");
        listOfNames.add("mKorbel");
        listOfNames.add("kleopatra");
        listOfNames.add("Reimeus");
        listOfNames.add("StanislavL");
        listOfNames.add("Paul Samsotha");
        listOfNames.add("Guillaume Polet");
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(TestApp::new);
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestApp");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jComboBox1 = new JComboBox<>(new DefaultComboBoxModel(listOfNames.toArray()));

        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name:");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                comboFilter(textField.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                comboFilter(textField.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                // plain text components dont fire this
            }
        });

        JButton showKeyboardButton = new JButton("Show Keyboard");
        showKeyboardButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            new DialogVirtualKeyboardReal(frame, true, textField);
        });

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(nameLabel);
        panel.add(textField);
        panel.add(showKeyboardButton);

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(jComboBox1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        new DialogVirtualKeyboardReal(frame, false, textField);
    }

    public void comboFilter(String enteredText) {
        List<String> filterArray = new ArrayList<>();

        listOfNames.forEach((item) -> {
            if (item.contains(enteredText)) {
                filterArray.add(item);
            }
        });

        if (filterArray.size() > 0) {
            jComboBox1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(filterArray.toArray()));
            //jComboBox1.showPopup();
        } else {
            //jComboBox1.hidePopup();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: #1 doesn't work for me. The program freezes. Because the documentListener is continuously getting names from mysql database. How can I stop it from doing so? Like how keypressed works